# Missing object in queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    is_active = models.BooleanField()
    created = models.DateTimeField()
```

And two CBVs: PostListView и PostDetailView.

```
queryset = Post.objects.filter(is_active=True, created__lt=timezone.now())
```

In both cases.

Problem: every 2nd PostListView rendering response without one Post instance with `created=datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 29, 13, 40, tzinfo=<UTC>)`. PostDetailView returning 404 (every 2nd response!). Its allright, when Im trying to reproduce bug in shell:

```
>>> Post.objects.filter(is_active=True, created__lte=timezone.now())
[<Post: 1>, <Post: 2>]
>>> Post.objects.filter(is_active=True, created__lte=timezone.now())
[<Post: 1>, <Post: 2>]
>>> Post.objects.filter(is_active=True, created__lte=timezone.now())
[<Post: 1>, <Post: 2>]
>>> Post.objects.filter(is_active=True, created__lte=timezone.now())
[<Post: 1>, <Post: 2>]
```

**Update**:

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(is_active=True, created__lt=timezone.now())
    context_object_name = 'posts'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['recommended'] = self.get_queryset().filter(is_recommended=True)[:5]
        return context


class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(is_active=True, created__lt=timezone.now())
    context_object_name = 'post'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['recommended'] = self.get_queryset().filter(is_recommended=True)[:5]
        return context


print self.get_queryset().query
SELECT `blog_post`.`id`, `blog_post`.`title`, `blog_post`.`slug`, `blog_post`.`meta_description`, `blog_post`.`img`, `blog_post`.`announcement`, `blog_post`.`content`, `blog_post`.`author_id`, `blog_post`.`is_innovation`, `blog_post`.`is_recommended`, `blog_post`.`is_active`, `blog_post`.`created` FROM `blog_post` WHERE (`blog_post`.`created` < 2014-06-04 15:02:44  AND `blog_post`.`is_active` = True ) ORDER BY `blog_post`.`created` DESC
```

> > > print Post.objects.filter(is_active=True, created__lt=timezone.now()).query
> > >       SELECT `blog_post`.`id`, `blog_post`.`title`, `blog_post`.`slug`, `blog_post`.`meta_description`, `blog_post`.`img`, `blog_post`.`announcement`, `blog_post`.`content`, `blog_post`.`author_id`, `blog_post`.`is_innovation`, `blog_post`.`is_recommended`, `blog_post`.`is_active`, `blog_post`.`created` FROM `blog_post` WHERE (`blog_post`.`created` < 2014-06-04 15:11:42  AND `blog_post`.`is_active` = True ) ORDER BY `blog_post`.`created` DESC

Running on nginx + gunicorn + gevent (Ubuntu server, MySQL).

Comment: More details about your views PostListView and PostDetailView?

Comment: put `print queryset.query` into your view and compare it with the same thing in console if there isnt some difference

Comment: Are you on the integrated development server or running "live". If live, try to restart your server if you changed your source code recently...

Comment: It could be something with service architecture. Do you have several servers running with load balancer? How do you launch your server to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @AlexShkop I tried to reproduce the issue in shell (the issue probably associated with "created" field)

Comment: What version of django you are using ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to use a function call for the queryset filter, you can't set it as an attribute. You must override `get_queryset`.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = super(PostListView, self).get_queryset()
    return queryset.filter(is_active=True, created__lt=timezone.now())
```

The reason is because timezone.now() will always return the value of when the class was first compiled. You might be able to get away with using `.filter(created__lt=timezone.now)` but I haven't tried that.